# The order of Aims, Objectives, and Research Question in the grant proposal application

Tags: application, funding, research-proposal

What should be the order of my Research Questions, Aim, and Order in response to the following section. The order that looks logical to me is **Research Question => Aim => Objective** . Any suggestion?

> ***Aims and Objectives (up to 100 words):** Please state what the proposed project intends to achieve, what the achievements will look like, and what tangible activities and benefits are expected. This may
> include a statement of research questions, if appropriate.*

The manner that looks natural to me is the following. Any suggestions?

> **Research Question**
>
> - This is the research question that has intrigued me.
>
> **Aim**
>
> - This is my aim that I want to achieve.
>
> **Objective**
>
> - This is Obj 1 that I will deliver.
> - This is Obj 2 that I will deliver.